# How do I remove extra unwanted space in kivy BoxLayout?

Tags: kivy, space

[image: remove extra black space]

```
<BoxExample@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            text: "Logo"
            size_hint: None, None
            width: "80dp"
            height: "40dp"
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        Button:
            text: "Menu"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: "40dp"
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
    Button:
        text: "Body"
    Button:
        text: "Footer"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "40dp"
```

**That black space in the picture above, which I want to get rid of.**
However after adding size_hint_y: None the gap has been narrowed as in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to BoxLayout which provides each of its child widgets equal space but here you have changed the size of buttons which are inside of BoxLayout.You also need to change the size of BoxLayout Otherwise it will show black.

```
<BoxExample@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: None,None
        size:root.size[0],"40dp"
        Button:
            text: "Logo"
            size_hint: None, None
            width: "80dp"
            height: "40dp"
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        Button:
            text: "Menu"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: "40dp"
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
    Button:
        text: "Body"
    Button:
        text: "Footer"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "40dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
height: self.minimum_height
```

to the `BoxLayout`:

```
<BoxExample@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        Button:
            text: "Logo"
            size_hint: None, None
            width: "80dp"
            height: "40dp"
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        Button:
            text: "Menu"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: "40dp"
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
    Button:
        text: "Body"
    Button:
        text: "Footer"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "40dp"
```